# Get uiview section under uiimageview?

Tags: ios, crop

I have an UIView as background, and a UIImageView above it.

[image][image]

What I want to do is fill the UIImageView with the UIView section that is in the back (without the white border)

[image]

I tried cropping a snapshot of the background but it doesnt look good. there is always a difference.

Comment: post the cropping code, you could have forgot the scale parameter in image context

Answer (score 0):

Make the background UIView a subview of the UIImageView and then set the property of the UIImageView `yourImageView.clipsToBounds = YES`

Answer (score 0):

Use CALayer mask. The mask will be the smaller image view, and will be assigned to the background view's mask property.

Comment: I cant figure out how to return an UIImage from a mask layer. I need this image to apply an efect inside the UIImageView